Upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04 oops sorry 20.04 not 22.04
I finally spent the time to figure out which file was preventing my upgrade, and proceeded to upgrade my desktop to 20.04 (on my way to 24.04). It was nearly finished when an option was shown for a script file (start up ??). Options were; use old, update to new, compare scripts. I chose compare, and that is when everything fell apart. I believe the upgrade was almost complete, except for the script. When attempting to reboot, I can get through the drive encryption, but after was stuck on a blank screen. Using a live cd/dvd copy, I have backed up everything from the main partition (for lack of a better term) but not the boot partition because I believe this is where the problem is.
Is there a way to fix this without formatting and installing a new OS copy?
Sorry I meant 20.04 not 22.04 and not skipping upgrades trying to do in order and properly. Desktop computer and desktop OS, NOT server.

Welcome to ASK. At the blank screen can you get a terminal? CTL ALT F3 (4, 5 etc) and CTL ATL F2 to get back CTL F1 for a new login.

Thank you. ctrl/alt/f3 - I get a terminal ? screen that at the top states: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS robert-desktop tty3   which tells me two things; the upgrade is complete, the gui desktop is not loading.  Also, yes I could still use a little help here.

The 20.04.6 wouldn't tell me the upgrade is complete... as I'd consider it only an indication that the base-files package has been upgraded to focal or 20.04 and nothing more. I'd more likely explore myself; eg. sudo apt update & ensure everything is good there; no missing lines, no warnings/errors & all correct. Next I'd apply all fixes via sudo apt full-upgrade where no warnings, errors or package upgrades should appear. At that point only, would I reboot & then check out the new system. If I had any doubt it was good, I'd probably explore other packages too; not just base-files.

Boot from a Live USB/DVD: Start your computer using a Live USB/DVD of Ubuntu.
Open Terminal: Open a terminal in the live environment.
Mount Your System: Find your system partition (e.g., /dev/sda2) using:
sudo fdisk -l

Then mount it by running the following:
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt

Fix GRUB: Run these commands to reinstall GRUB:
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda  # Replace /dev/sda with your drive
update-grub
exit

Unmount and Reboot: Unmount everything and reboot:
sudo umount /mnt/dev /mnt/proc /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot

This should fix the boot issue. If it doesn't, let me know. By the way, let me know if you found this answer helpful because I have honestly never had this problem.

sudo fdisk -l  sda1 - boot partition, sda2 extended, sda3 files etc. so I'm going with sda1.    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt; seemed to work    sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev   ->mount point does not exist... Do I have to add /sda1 after dev or do i replace /dev with sda1???
